# Terminate a forked process (forwarding a port)

Tags: ruby, oracle, ssh

I installed an Oracle thin client on my local machine to execute SQL commands on a remote host.
Also, I have a Ruby script that contains SQL commands (using the OCI8 gem) and the script is working correctly.

However, to run the SQL commands I need to open a tunnel, forwarding to the port the remote Oracle is listening to:

```
ssh -L 1521:localhost:1521 <user>@<host>
```

Running this command logs me into the remote host, which I do not want.

I found the following command to run which creates a tunnel, forwarding the specific port, and I can run the Ruby script, containing the SQL commands, successfully.

```
tunnel = fork do
    exec "ssh -f <user>@<host> -L 1521:localhost:1521 -N"
end
```

So, the tunnel is created in the background, however, I also need to terminate the tunnel, disconnect from the remote instance. I tried the following:

```
 Process.kill('HUP', tunnel)
```

However, the tunnel is not killed.

Is there a way that I can kill/terminate the tunnel from within the Ruby script?

Answer (score 0):

A `HUP` signal doesn't kill a process, that just sends it a signal and that process is free to ignore it. `HUP` is often used to signal that a configuration file should be reloaded.

What you want is:

```
Process.kill('INT', tunnel)
```

A more aggressive version for situations where asking politely doesn't work:

```
Process.kill('KILL', tunnel)
```

Comment: thanks for the info. Yet your solution did not work, the tunnel is still being kept open. I can still run the ruby script successfully running sql commands against the remote oracle database instance

Comment: Ah, of course. The `-f` option creates a sub-subprocess that you can't kill without tracking which PID that one has, it's become detached. If you can avoid `-f`, you can manage the tunnel directly.

Comment: thanks for the update. tadman. for now I found a workaround, still using -f, but I removed the "-N" flag and instead pass a sleep value,                              exec "ssh -f <user>@<host> -L 1521:localhost:1521 sleep 60"                         this way the tunnel is created but terminated after the sleep time has been reached.